# Como evitar guardar en mi bases de datos estos símbolos &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;

Tags: php, html, mysql, ckeditor

tengo un inconveniente al momento de guardar la información de un editor de texto lo cual cuando guardo las etiquetas html me las guardas así 
<p><strong>

Vista del editor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo evitar este error

Gracias

Comment: Amigo a mi me paso una vez primero toca definir el charset utf8, y luego en la base de datos el campo debes crearlo como longtext. así es que hago yo cuando trabajo con editores como ckeditor.

Comment: Usa mysqli_real_escape_string > http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.real-escape-string.php en vez de html_entities, html_entities convertirá tu contenido a ese resultado. Mientras que mysqli_real_escape_string limpiará tu contenido de posibles inyecciones

Comment: en mi bases de datos ya la tengo como longtext , utilizo la etiqueta de angular para mostrar el contenido ng-bind-html pero en la bases de datos me guarda los símbolos

Comment: estoy utilizando codeignaiter lo utilizo donde directamente hago envió la bases de datos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hola encontré una solución, que es donde se renderiza en la vista agregar el html_entity_decode,

```html
'description' =>html_entity_decode($item['description'])
```

ejemplo

```html
<?
$b = html_entity_decode("<strong>Prueba</strong>");
echo $b; 
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Para evitar la codificacion de entidades de HTML, como lo hace la función html_entities():

- Si estás usando MySQLi: usa [mysqli_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).
- Si usas MySQL, entonces usa [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).
- Si usas PDO, entonces [parametriza tus consultas](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Ahora bien, si quieres una función propia para *"limpiar"* los datos de usuario, puedes usar lo siguiente:

```
<?php
    $data_usuario = $_POST['userdata'];  // <script>alert('hacked');</script>
    function limpiar_data($data){
        $limpio = preg_replace(['/[^A-z0-9 +@-_\.\|\/\*\-\+\=]+/', '/\s+/'], ['', ' '], $data);
        return $limpio;
    }
    echo limpiar_data($data_usuario); // scriptalerthacked/script
```

Comment: gracias por sus ayuda pero como tal estoy utilizando codeignaiter ,no se si eso interfiera ?,por que me guarda los datos pero me muestras las etiquetas

Comment: En alguna parte de tu código estás usando la funcion de codificación, como `html_entities()`, o `htmlspecialchars()`

Comment: Lo utiliza  pero esta en algunos plugins htmlspecialchars()

Comment: Bueno, eso puede ser la raíz del problema, intenta quitar la función y dejarlo pasando la variable pura e intenta nuevamente insertar a la base de datos a ver qué tal

Comment: La modifique pero no funciona estoy tratando de configurar el ckeditor ,para que envié las etiquetas gracias por tu comentario